# Update mysql table every twenty four hours automatically

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I was wondering how I could set up a script (I'm assuming it would be a cron job) that would reset a field in a mysql table every twenty four hours back to zero. I would want it to reset the field for every user not just a specific person. I know nothing about cron jobs unfortunately, but maybe I don't even need to use them. I am very unsure on how to solve this issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using the MySql event scheduler itself?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

create a python script that connects to the mysql table and performs the update query.

Create a cron job that runs 1 time every day that executes:

python updateValue.py

It is quite easy, and the best way I can think of doing it.

The crontab argument would look like:

```
0 0 * * * python updateValue.py
```

Comment: Why even complicate this with python when you could call the mysql client and execute a statement from there?

Comment: @AdrianCornish - Would not be dangerous to expose your mysql username and password on the crontab?

Comment: Possibly but if I can access the crontab then I can access the python script. Also mysql permission for localhost access can be set so no password is required

Comment: Too complicated as it is stated in previous comments, plus insecure. MYSQL event scheduler is the way to go.